# Gempy plot3d.surfaces?

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm having some problems with the gempy library, the picture below is the reason for my error, please tell me how to solve this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t87XL.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXJIQ.png)
I don't know how to solve this problem

Comment: I'm sorry about that.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577) Instead, format code as a [code block]. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.